# How to get contact number from telegram user via Telegram bot api?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Is it possible for telegram bots to obtain the user's phone number after they have started the bot (without explicitly asking the user to input their contact details)?

If so, how do I achieve this using Telegram bot api or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For privacy reasons, it's absolutely impossible.**

These are everything that bot knows about a user:

| Field | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | Integer |
| is_bot | Boolean |
| first_name | String |
| last_name | String |
| username | String |
| language_code | String |
| can_join_groups | Boolean |
| can_read_all_group_messages | Boolean |
| supports_inline_queries | Boolean |

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user

Answer (score 1):

I found your asking randomly

You must send user **KeyboardButton**, but **Button** must have option **"request_contact" = true**.

[Screenshot from docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36gyy.png)

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton